# Change value based on circumstances, and save to SharedPreferences. If circumstances change, assign new value instead of loading previous one

Tags: android, android-studio, save, sharedpreferences

It sounds a bit confusing, but what I am trying to do is to have an if statement that dictates whether or not boolean values are true or false. Only one boolean value can be true at a time.
If boolean A is true, then I want to add +5 to the value, if boolean B is true, then I want to add +10.

This all works fine, however, as I save it in the SharedPreferences, when the circumstances change and say, at first Boolean A was true, adding +5 to the value, and now boolean B is true, it adds +10 to the value on top of the 5, totalling up to +15.

What I want, is to keep the original values, so if B is true, instead of the added value totalling 15, I want it to total 10.

```
public class TestPrefs extends AppCompatActivity {

public int Value;

Boolean A, B, C;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_prefs);


    SharedPreferences GetBoolean = getSharedPreferences("BOOLEANGET", MODE_PRIVATE);
    A = GetBoolean.getBoolean("BOOLEANA", false);
    B = GetBoolean.getBoolean("BOOLEANB", false);
    C = GetBoolean.getBoolean("BOOLEANC", false);

    if (A == true) {
        Value = Value + 5;
    } else if (B == true) {
        Value = Value + 10;
    } else if (C == true) {
        Value = Value + 15;
    }


   SaveValue();
}

public void  SaveValue () {

    SharedPreferences ValuePass = getSharedPreferences("VALUES", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor VEDIT = ValuePass.edit();
    VEDIT.putInt("Value", Value);
    VEDIT.apply();
    
}
```

Everything here is working fine, but the saved value always just adds new value on top of the old one. I want it to exchange the values, so if it switches from a to b, to minus A from it and add B only.

Comment: Hi. you need to add VEDIT.apply(); after VEDIT.putInt("Value", Value); . And you need to use  the same name in getSharedPreferences: "BOOLEANGET" or "VALUES".

Comment: So you want the sum of exactly one type ? if A has an old point of 20 and B has 30 and C  has 50 , so when A has a new value , it should be added to just 20 ?

Comment: @Alexy Hello, I made the neccessary changes. I am using BOOLEANGET to get boolean values from another activity, so that one is fine.

Comment: @Mustafa Yes I want to add the value of exactly one type. If the value is already 10, and if Boolean A is true, Value = Value + 5; or if B is true, Value = Value +10.

Comment: Can you tell what are you trying to do by all that so i can make it even simple , cause its totally mess right now , and i didn't understand anything .